# jQuery css background position change twice

Tags: jquery, background-position, animate.css

I'm basically trying to alter the background-position on a div twice in fairly quick succesion . Heres my current code:

```
$('.slide1').css({'margin':' 0 0 0 1000px','display':'none'}).delay(2400).show().animate({marginLeft: 0},1000, function(){ 
        $('.accordion').css('background','#000'); 
        $('.shadow-horizontal').css('visibility','visible');
        $('.panel:nth-child(2)').delay(2000).css('background-position','0px top'); //this one doesn't seem to fire
        $('.panel:nth-child(2)').delay(2000).css('background-position','-410px top'); //this one does 
    });
```

Whats happening is only the second change is taking place. The first one doesn't seem to be affected at all.

I'll note that I need to do it using jQuery and ideally I'd prefer to wrap the jquery .css changes in a function and just call that were the current jQuery .css changes are.

I also tried a long string version too that didn't work.

```
$('.panel:nth-child(1)').css('background-position','0px top').delay(500).css('background-position','-41px top');
```

Here's a live version of where I'm at: http://faithandsony.co.uk/sony_accordion_hover-hightlight/

Thanks in advance for any answers. I'm around to answer any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could just be a timing issue. You could use a simple `timeout()` to perform the first before the second, making the second CSS change wait 1000ms (or 1 second) before executing.

```
$('.panel:nth-child(2)').delay(2000).css('background-position','0px top');

setTimeout(function() {
    $('.panel:nth-child(2)').css('background-position','-410px top');
}, 4000);
```

---

Alternatively, keep the delay for the first at 2000, and change the second to 4000, giving:

```
$('.panel:nth-child(2)').delay(2000).css('background-position','0px top'); 
$('.panel:nth-child(2)').delay(4000).css('background-position','-410px top');
```

Comment: Well that seems to have worked just fine, thank you. But why did my delays not work? I thought I'd covered any potential timing issues with the delays? How I did have a suspicsion there was something to do with how jQuery builds the list of things it has to do and delay does work in the same way as setTimeout.

Comment: I think that the CSS delays are executing at the same time from before you execute both. As a result, they're **both** executing 2000 seconds after the previous line :) You kinda have to stack them up for `.css()`. If you'd used *animations* though, like `fadeOut()`, you could have set callbacks which only execute after they have completed like: $('.panel:nth-child(2)').fadeOut('2000', function() { // Now that has finished, do something else... }); - CSS doesn't have these unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

delay only work with animate,

to keep it's use, just do an empty animate

```
$('.panel:nth-child(2)').delay(2000).animate({},function()
{ $(this).css('background-position','0 top');
}).delay(2000).animate({},function()
{ $(this).css('background-position','-410px top');
});
```

and if it's not work with empty {}, try animate a dumb parameter
if you always get by exemple margin:0, animate him :

```
animate({margin:0},time,callback);
```

Comment: Adding a redundant `animate()` function is a little too hacky for my liking.

Comment: but take care about delay ONLY work with jquery.queue and jquery fx (who use queue too)
all that is not queue or fx will NOT be impacted by the delay and executed directly, like the .css()

you need use setTimeout or animate hack